# monk vs mongoose for Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, monk

I'm learning NodeJs.

To connect to and use MongoDB from NodeJS, I see a lot of examples using either Monk or Mongoose.

Are these two libraries equivalent ? Do they have the same features or do they each have a specific purpose ?

As a beginner with NodeJS, which should I use ?

Here are some examples of code that uses Monk :

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/nodejsapp');

----
exports.userlist = function(db) {
    return function(req, res) {
        var collection = db.get('users');
        collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
            res.render('userlist', {
                "userlist" : docs
            });
        });
    };
};
```

and here a sample that uses Mongoose :

```
   var mongoose = require('mongoose');
----
 mongoose.connect('localhost', 'test');
 var db = mongoose.connection;
  db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
  db.once('open', function callback() {
   console.log('Connected to DB');
});

// User Schema
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
   email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true},
});
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

> are they same thing do the same connection ? or do they have specific purpose ?

They are different, although they are two approaches to the same basic problem. Mongoose is a quite sophisticated full-on ORM. More features, but more complexity. Monk is smaller in scope and thus easier to understand.

My suggestion is start coding with the basic `mongodb` driver module directly. When you understand how that works, and how parts of it are annoying, you will understand the benefit of `monk` and can try that out to see if you like it. I wouldn't recommend `mongoose` to a beginner. Mongodb is already tricky enough to learn and while mongoose can be helpful, it's API is quite magical and assumes you already know the tricky aspects of mongodb.

Comment: I started with Mongoose and didn't have a problem. Their website had excellent documentation and examples of basic CRUD.

Comment: i recommend monk for the beginners, understanding monk documentation is easy quick

Answer (score 29):

If you are learning NodeJS and Mongo, you really dont need anything else -- in fact, MongoDB offers a free online class for MongoDB and NodeJS developers.  No need for any additional wrappers.

See https://university.mongodb.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is a new ORM called mongo-strict

Mongo Strict is a TypeScript-based smart MongoDB ORM that makes the usage of MongoDB safer, easier, and faster, with improved performance. Mongo-strict provides the safety of SQL databases while retaining the flexibility and ease of use of MongoDB. mongo-strict MongoDB ORM for NodeJS

You can give it a try
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-strict