# How to do passport.js with monk instead of mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js, monk

I started with monk instead of mongoose - and I really would be happy to stay this way!

My concrete problem: 
How to transfer or better 'adapt' this following functionalities - that exists in a lot of node/mongoose/passport.js tutorials - with monk?

This is the snippet for mongoose:

---

// app/models/user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
```

// define the schema for our user model

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({..})
```

// generating a hash

```
userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {
return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);};
```

// checking if password is valid

```
userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password);};
```

// create the model for users and expose it to our app

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Well I have a monk schema already, but how to go on?
Could anybody gives me a hint to have an equivalent for the two bcrypt functionalities and model creation & backpassing with monk?

Comment: Why you need a equivalent of bcrypt functions? Basically you just changed the mongodb api. The logic still the same.

Comment: I think this post will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23615377/monk-vs-mongoose-for-mongodb

Comment: Yes, I know this post already. I have no intentions to use pure mongodb, I like the idea of monk as layer. ..and if mongoose offers solution as ".model" creation and  "instance methods" I would like to know how to with monk - except of cource this is no playground for monk?